# How to delete depricated string fields in options document?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Lets say I have a collections 'testCol' with document validation options in its options document.

```
{
     "name" : "testCol",
     "type" : "collection",
     "options" : {
         "validator" : {
             "$or" : [
                 {
                     "phone" : {
                         "$type" : "string"
                     }
                 },
             ]
         },
         "validationLevel" : "moderate",
         "validationAction" : "error"
     },
     ...
}
```

Lets also say I want to delete these options (I am aware that I can set 'validationLevel' to 'off').
I can run `db.runCommand('colMod'': testCol', validator: {})` and mongoDB will delete the field 'validator' from the options document. But I can't do the same for 'validationLevel' and 'validationAction'. `db.runCommand('colMod'': testCol', validationLevel: '')`, does not change anything which leaves me with something like this:

```
{
        "name" : "testCol",
        "type" : "collection",
        "options" : {
            "validationLevel" : "moderate",
            "validationAction" : "error"
        },
        ...
}
```

This is just unclean! Is there a way to get rid of that deprecated string-field options or a way to manipulate/access the options document of a collection directly?

Comment: You said you want to delete all the `options`. In that case, why not set options to emtpy object `db.runCommand('colMod'': testCol', options: {})` instead of setting validator to empty object `db.runCommand('colMod'': testCol', validator: {})`?

Comment: I do not want to delete ALL options. Just these specific ones.